# Trying to select a dropdown item that is a random GUID

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm relatively new to Webdriver, and I am wondering if it is possible to select items on a dropdown that use a guid.

Normally, I would use

```
new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("location"))).selectByVisibleText("value");
```

However, as the page is using a random identifier for each of the dropdowns which change with each load of the page it is making it extremely difficult to automate!

When the DOB as a whole has been completed, it's ID is 'DateOFBirth'

If I could get some help with this, it would be greatly appreciated,

This the element for the "Date" dropdown

```
<select class="valid" aria-invalid="false"id="a9fbd53c8d354e4b8a5d74c5ad1499d5" name="DateOfBirth.a9fbd53c8d354e4b8a5d74c5ad1499d5" onchange="OnChangeDateOfBirth('a9fbd53c8d354e4b8a5d74c5ad1499d5', '190a3115711d4415aeaf6bf7fc658e2b', '3dbf7448224e4042ac1e477abc345981', 'DateOfBirth');">
```

It doesn't seem that there are any singulairties at all when the page is refreshed. is there any way I could start it using the default value? which is "Date:"

### Update

- I managed to resolve this using xpaths

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content-holder']/ul/li[3]/ul/li[5]/fieldset/select"))).selectByVisibleText("14");
```

Comment: Do they have any constant part or are they completely random? Further, do they have a fixed order so you could use selectByIndex? If none of those apply I do not think that you can test it automatically and maybe you should have a talk with a developer about implementing unique identifiers.

Comment: We use Angular/Material which also generated random unreliable IDs. So we use tags or names and other tricks to find relevant element. Name is usually good enough, but in case you have multiple elements with same name, you can get a list and loop over it investigating other attributes.

Comment: I'll have a play around with these, if not I'll chat with the devs. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use css selectors like these:

```
select[name*='DateOfBirth']
select[onchange*='DateOfBirth']
#content-holder select[name*='DateOfBirth']
#content-holder select[onchange*='DateOfBirth']
```